# How to write java thread pool programme to read content of file?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I want to define thread pool with 10 threads and read the content of the file. But different threads must not read same content.(like divide content into 10 pieces and read each pieces by one thread)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well what you would do would be roughly this:

1. get the length of the file,
2. divide by N.
3. create N threads
4. have each one skip to `(file_size / N) * thread_no` and read `(file_size / N)` bytes into a buffer
5. wait for all threads to complete.
6. stitch the buffers together.

(If you were slightly clever about it, you could avoid the last step ...)

HOWEVER, it is doubtful that you would get much speed-up by doing this.  Indeed, I wouldn't be surprised if you got a slow down in many cases.  With a typical OS, I would expect that you would get as good, if not better performance by reading the file using one big `read(...)` call from one thread.

The OS can fetch the data faster from the disc if you read it sequentially.  Indeed, a lot of OSes optimize for this use-case, and use read-ahead and in-memory buffering (using OS-level buffers) to give high effective file read rates.

Reading a file with multiple threads means that each thread will typically be reading from a different position in the file.  Naively, that would entail the OS to seeking the disk heads backwards and forwards between the different positions ... which will slow down I/O considerably.  In practice, the OS will do various things to mitigate that, but even so, simultaneously reading data from different positions on a disk is still bad for I/O throughput.